# Exposing Spark Worker (stdout stderr) logs in Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I have a Spark Cluster with one Master and 4 Workers running in a 3 Node Kubernetes Cluster.
The Spark UI and Master are exposed through Ingress/NodePort and is hence accessible from outside the Kubernetes cluster.

But, the worker ports are not exposed.
**Due to this, the Worker logs (stdout and stderr) are not accessible through the UI.**
The logs URL is getting redirected to `<Worker1_Pod_IP:8080>` , `<Worker2_Pod_IP:8080>` and so on.

**My setup is such that there are two worker pods running on the same machine. So even if I NodePort expose the workers, there will be a conflict in ports as the same port will be assigned for the two workers on the machine.**
Spark History server only provides Event Logs and not Worker logs.

How can this be solved? Is there a way the NodePort value can be dynamically assigned for the workers

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about the `SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT` and not the `SPARK_WORKER_PORT` as described below since that its assigned a random port.

[image: Spark]

This is a bit tricky because you can only expose a single port per node. If you have two spark workers per node you could create two deployments for your nodes, one that exposes the `SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT` on `8081` and another on `8082` and also make sure that only one pod is scheduled per node.

You can pass these values in the [container environment varialbles](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/)

Comment: I'm aware of this. But our requirement restricts us from having one worker per machine. Hence the issue.

Comment: Thanks..But that is not exactly what we are looking for

Comment: @RamKrishnan - agree - the big benefit would be to squeeze many workers on 1 node. Have you found any resolution to this issue?

Comment: Are you running spark natively on Kubernetes? With their built-in operator?

Comment: Were you able to find a way to expose stdout, stderr to history server?